# How to handle PUT request?

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js, put, use-form

It may be an easy question but being a beginner I'm having issues while handling **PUT** requests. I have to update my form and save it to the database.
I'm using Next.js and React. My protected request function is written as follows:

```
export async function handlePut(path, data, token) {
  return await axios.put(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + path, data, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
}

export async function protectedRequest(path, type, session, data = null) {
  switch (type) {
    case "GET":
      return await handleGet(path, session.accessToken);
    case "POST":
      return await handlePost(path, data, session.accessToken);
    case "PUT":
      return await handlePut(path, data, session.accessToken);
    case "DELETE":
      return await handleDel(path, session.accessToken);
    default:
      throw "Invalid request ";
  }
}
```

My code is like this:

```
export default function UserProfile(props) {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [user, setUser] = useState([props.userProfile]);

  const form = useForm({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      surname: "",
      email: "",
    },

  function handleSubmit(values) {
    console.warn(values);
    let updatedUser = protectedRequest("****(API endpoint)", "PUT", session,values)
      .then((response) => {
        let updatedData = response.data.data;
        console.log(updatedData)
      })
      .catch((error) => handleError(error));        
   }

  const page = (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Space h="xl" />
        <div className="border-1-4 border-gray-100 bg-white py-4 px-5">
          {user.map((data) => (
            <form
              method="post"
              className="pt-5"
              key={data.data.id}
              onSubmit={form.onSubmit(handleSubmit)}
            >

                  <TextInput
                    label="Name"
                    placeholder={data.data.name}
                    {...form.getInputProps("name")}
                  />
             
                  <TextInput
                    label="Surname"
                    placeholder={data.data.surname}
                    {...form.getInputProps("surname")}
                  />

              <EmailField
                required
                name="email"
                label="Email"
                placeholder={data.data.email}
                {...form.getInputProps("email")}
              />
             <button type="submit">Save</button>                 
            </form>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );    
  return page;
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session || session?.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: `/api/auth/signin`,
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  let userProfile = await protectedRequest("/users/self", "GET", session).catch(
    () => {
      return { data: { data: [] } };
    },
  );
  return {
    props: {
      userProfile: userProfile.data,
    },
  };
}
```

I'm getting errors while updating the form. I'm a beginner to Next.js so confused about how to handle PUT requests. GET request is working fine and I'm able to fetch data.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: *"I'm getting errors"* - Have you looked at the error messages?

Comment: Yes.       Request failed with status code 400

Comment: That means the server responded with a "Bad Request" status code.  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the request what you expect?  If so then you need to examine/debug the server-side code.

Comment: Does your backend actually support PUT requests?